# python+openCV : only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, opencv

This is my code to rotate the img with cv2.getRotationMatrix2D() function.

```
smoothed_angle = 0

img = cv2.imread("/home/hp/self driving car/steering_wheel_image.png")
print(img.shape) #outputs (240, 240, 3)
rows = img.shape[0]
print(rows) #outputs 240
cols = img.shape[1]
print(cols) #outputs 240

M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),-smoothed_angle,1)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-55419a87d5b5> in <module>()
     34 #and the predicted angle
     35 smoothed_angle += 0.2 * pow(abs((predicted_angle_degree - smoothed_angle)), 2.0 / 3.0) * (predicted_angle_degree - smoothed_angle) / abs(predicted_angle_degree - smoothed_angle)
---> 36 M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),-smoothed_angle,1)
     37 dst = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(cols,rows))
     38 #cv2.imshow("steering wheel", dst)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Also, `print(type(smoothed_angle))` gives the following output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: What does `print(type(smoothed_angle))` give you right before the call to `getRotationMatrix2D`?

Comment: @djhoese : <class 'numpy.ndarray'> . I edited the description of my question.

Comment: Hi i think its due to numpy version mismatch.
cause the code snippet you provided works fine for me without any error.
Edit i think the error is in the line where you calculate "smoothened angle" and its somehow being calculated an array having length grater then 1 and thus the error. But since now the angle is an array but it needs the scaler the error is thrown.

Answer (score 4):

The example script doesn't return an error as it is written.  But in your error output, there's a line 35 that says:

```
     35 smoothed_angle += 0.2 * pow(abs((predicted_angle_degree - smoothed_angle)), 2.0 / 3.0) * (predicted_angle_degree - smoothed_angle) / abs(predicted_angle_degree - smoothed_angle)
```

This isn't in the example script, but might be a source of the problem (or another step that isn't in the example).  If you start with `smoothed_angle = 0` but `predicted_angle_degree` is an array instead of a scalar (e.g. `predicted_angle_degree = np.array([0,0])`), it will result in the error shown.  So it looks to be that the error is due to `smoothed_angle` not being a scalar.

*Update with the type info*: As shown with the type for `smoothed_angle`, it's not a scalar or it would have printed `<type 'int'>` or `<type 'float'>`.  If `smoothed_angle` did start as a scalar like in the example, then it's being changed by another function not given in the example, like the one in line 35.  This would also mean that another parameter that's being used to update `smoothed_angle`, such as `predicted_angle_degree`, also has type `ndarray`.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking and why I asked the type question. Good answer.

Comment: Yeah. predicted_angle_degree is also of ndarray. So what do u suggest? Use a loop and calculate the smoothed_angle for each element of predicted_angle_degree?

Comment: It depends on what the goal of the code is, and what the variables are. Are you wanting to calculate a single angle for the image? What is predicted_angle_degree and how is it calculated? Is it an array of angles or is it supposed to be used to calculate a single angle?

Comment: @AKruger : predicted_angle_degree is an array of angles. I want to calculate a single smoothed_angle for each image. There are 600 images.

Comment: In that case, if each element in `predicted_angle_degree` is for a different image, then yeah, use one element at a time to get the angle for each image.  You will also need to have a different rotation matrix for each image.  And, yeah, you can use a loop for that.